# jquery mobile does not work in production rails 3.2 app

Tags: jquery-mobile, ruby-on-rails-3.2, asset-pipeline, passenger

I have a Rails 3.2.9 app using jquery mobile.

I use the jquery_mobile_rails gem to embed jqm and the mobylette gem to detect when requests come from a mobile device.

All works ok in development environment (Webrick)

The production env is based on apache/passenger.
when I run rake assets:precompile all seems to go well,
and if I look at assets/manifest.yml I can see that all seems ok.

When I invoke the welcome page the login form is sent to the browser,
but while in development env the page has all the jqm formats,
in production the html is not "injected" with the needed JQM code,
so for example the  tag is simply

```
<body>
```

instead of

```
<body class="ui-mobile-viewport ui-overlay-c">
```

So it seems that after loading the page, the javascript that should run and "enrich" the html with JQM specific code is not triggered.

Any hint about why this is happening?

**EDIT**

```
assets
  javascripts
    application.js
    mobile
      application.js

views
  layouts
    application.html.erb
    application.mobile.erb
```

manifest files are:

```
javascripts/application.js

//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_directory .


javascripts/mobile/application.js

//= require jquery.mobile
//= require_directory .
```

Comment: Can you post your `application.js` ?

Comment: I edited the question to include the manifest files. I have jquery.mobile required in a subdir so it is not used in the part of the site that is not used by mobile devices. I do this by putting  '<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>' and '<%= javascript_include_tag "mobile/application" %>' in the mobile layout

Comment: can you please share your application.js we would see where is the problem..

Comment: Maybe I do not understand your request. I did already post right here the content of both application.js files. Anyway the problem has been solved (look hereunder), and the cause is that jquery 1.9 is incompatible with jquery mobile 1.2.0. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

In case you would like to include a bunch of files from a particular directory (or a library ) ,you can use [index manifest file](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#asset-organization) (look for 2.1.2). It is really simple:

- in your directory (`app/assets/javascripts/mobile`) create a file `index.js` with content :

  ```
  //= require_self
  //= require other_files_you_want
  ```

(and optionaly):

```
    //= require_tree .
```

- then in your `application.js` manifest file you can require the library with the name of the directory , in which you have created the `index.js` file :

  ```
  //= require mobile
  ```

I would suggest, when you pass these steps, to remove the file `app/assets/javascripts/mobile/application.js`. It is not a good style in one app to have more than one file with the name `application.js`.

EDIT (after taking a look at the `application.css`):

I would suggest a couple of corrections in your manifest file `application.css`:

- move the css code in a new file (for example `app/assets/stylesheets/custom.css.scss`)
- if there are others css libs that you use , include them like normal (`*= require your_css`) in your `application.css`.

Comment: I'll go and try to modify as you suggest, but I believe my problem lies somewhere else. The problem is that jqm libraries are loaded correctly, but my markup is not enhanced when page is loaded, and this only happens in production mode, while in dev mode all works ok.

Comment: Then we should look at your `application.css` :).

Comment: Anyway I cannot put //= require mobile in application.js because I want it loaded only for the application.mobile.erb template and not for application.html.erb.

Comment: application.css => http://pastiebin.com/511f41acd60f4; mobile/application.css => http://pastiebin.com/511f42c0abd08; 
mobile/mobileapp.css => http://pastiebin.com/511f430987fb7. Also, this is the url of the dev app http://redberry.dyndns-ip.com, and this is the url of the production app http://2.228.81.236

Comment: to see the difference you have to use a user agent that is detected as a mobile device by the mobylette gem (see https://github.com/tscolari/mobylette/blob/master/lib/mobylette/mobile_user_agents.rb)

Comment: Your mobile version looks fine , really. That's because your mobile-js library creates the css without your `application.css`. I will edit my answer.

Comment: I have just found that my shiny new Blackberry Z10 (it's a preview unit....) has a great tool to debug html pages. With web inspector i can do remote debug from my desktop chrome. Here i find a javascript error saying "TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'e.browser.msie')". Having javascript minified and compressed it is hard to say where the problem is, but now there is a trace. It is a jquery mobile problem, let's see which one...

Answer (score 0):

The problem was due to an incompatibility between the last versions of jquery and jquery mobile.

jquery mobile 1.2.0 released Oct 2 2012  has problems with last jquery version 1.9.x.

Specifically, jquery 1.9 removed the $.browser method, which is used in jquery mobile 1.2.0.

So when jqwery mobile tries to initialize objects on the page it dies with the error

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'e.browser.msie')
```

I solved the problem by forcing the use of jquery 1.8.3; in Gemfile

```
gem 'jquery-rails', '~> 2.1.4'
```

which includes jquery 1.8.3 in the assets pipeline.

Without web inspector on the BB Z10 (or remote debug function on android 4 devices) I would have never been able to detect such javascript problem on the mobile platform.

As a final tought, BlackBerry Z10 Web Inspector works via Wi-Fi, while Android devices need an USB connection to have remote debug work.